# Multiple connections per ip

Tags: networking, server, iptables, connection, nginx

I am running Ubuntu with a webserver (Nginx). I noticed that one IP has multiple connections opened. My server works all fine and there is no issue.

I am just curious to know why there are many connections opened by an IP? Could I see what actions that IP is performing per connection?

I used this command to get total number of connections per IP:

```
netstat -na | grep tcp | awk '{print $5}' | cut -f 1 -d : | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

It gives output like:

```
1 xxx
14 yyy
18 zzz
```

Where `xxx`, `yyy`, and `zzz` are IP addresses. Why do an IP needs to create more one connections on server?

I know that I can restrict 1 connection per IP using iptables. It is quite possible that these users might have some issues with internet, they refresh page and server creates a new connection for them without closing the previous one. In this case, restricting connections per IP might create some problems for the users.

Is it possible to close previous connection before opening a new connection?

PS: connections are on port 80

Comment: Their browser is probably creating multiple connections at once to speed up page loading (like downloading multiple images or js files at the same time).

Comment: You think limiting connections per ip OR restricting connections per 300 seconds would create a problem for users?

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance!  Question upvoted!  You're a reputation 8 user already!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time that a web server only had to server pure HTML, without cookies, pictures, videos, sound, JavaScript, ads, ... is long past.

Nowadays, a page is made up of multiple elements that can be downloaded simultaneously so that the page renders faster.

*Those* are the multiple IP connections you see.  You *could* limit them and your server would become faster, but then the clients loading of pages from your server, would slow down, so you *could do that, **but it's a bad idea...***

Comment: I open a page and it loads fast, I look on the total connections I opened are just 5-10. However, for some other people (for some weird reasons), their number of connections are over 200. Is it normal? Is there a way I can debug to see what each connection was doing?